# Cache Variable Scope in Cache Server Page (CSP)

Tags: javascript, intersystems-cache, objectscript

I am trying to store a temporary data in the CSP.

I try to avoid ^Global and %session due to concurrency concerns, and avoid Javascript variable due to security concerns.

Then I encounter a confusion. Codes below are all in one single CSP:

```
<script language="Cache" runat="server">
s test = 1
</script>
```

```
<script language="Cache" method="Update">
s test = 2
</script>
```

```
<script language="Javascript">
function init(){
 #server(..Update())#
 alert("#(test)#");
}
</script>
```

```
<body onload="init();"></body>
```

1. During the page onload, the alert return `test` as "1" rather than "2". What is happening here?
2. And is there any other better approach to store this kind of data in the CSP?

Comment: Why do you need CSP at all? Check the REST-API approach with InterSystems. e.g. https://community.intersystems.com/post/restful-api

Comment: I need CSP as it is part of the web application, and REST api is not set up. I can only use what I have now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#()# is executed during page rendering.

so you are getting page like following. Right click on generated page and view its source code.

```
<script language="Javascript">
function init(){
 #server(..Update())#
 alert("1");
}
</script>
```

Also, consider that generally, different CSP requests are handled by different server processes, so it's not a good idea to handle state in global variables.

If you need to keep data for each user session, best way is to use %session

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am suggested to avoid %session at its best due to the web application multi-tabbing features, and conflicts often occur between them.